# PHP and MongoDB - Adavanced Query

Tags: php, mongodb

Would be nice if someone knows some examples for my "Query".

If have an Collection with Prices and Timestamps, i have to query for the records withe the newest timestamp "only".

I could query for all records sorted by timestamp and do an second query with the newest timestamp from the result, but i suppose this is not the best way (500.000 records). Does someone knows an good way to do this with mongoDB and PHP5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a standard, auto-generated default '_id' primary field, that is timestamp based. Getting a single (`limit(1)`) in descending order will be the most recent document.

Beyond that, depends on the schema you are using.